# Scroll content inside slide (touch devices) in reveal.js

Tags: reveal.js

Is there possibility to scroll content inside the slide on touch devices? My content has vertical scroll bar at desktop view, but on touch devices I can't scroll content at all. I guess scroll event is catched by library and is treated as scrolling to nested vertical slides. I will be happy to get some help here, thank you in advance.